# Android camera auto exposure lock on taking multiple pictures

Tags: android, locking, android-camera, panoramas

I'm using auto exposure lock feature on android camera, but it's losing the lock after I take a picture, what I want is to lock exposure for taking a sevral pictures like for my case: I have to take a panorama pictures with the same exposure ( same exposure lock ).

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is possible, and I don't think it would be a good idea to lock exposure for panoramic images: light conditions may vary too strongly between fragments of would-be panorama.

Comment: everytime you start a Capture you must set Focus and Exposure to lock and update your preview. Later on, when you stop your captures request, set to unlocked both parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Thank you, I have done that by storing exposure, brightness and focus current level when taking the first picture, then lock everything to it's values everytime I take a picture I do relock them, because It loses the Lock everytime PictureTaken Callback.. I got A good Result

Get funcions

```
public int getExposure() {
    expousreSet = true;
    return parameters.getExposureCompensation();
}
```

Then

```
    if (exposureSet == true) {
        parameters.setExposureCompensation(currentExposure);
        parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
    }
```